# Installing Cognos BI without Framework Manager?

Tags: linux, frameworks, installation, cognos, cognos-bi

I've got the task now of installing Cognos BI 10.1.1 on our new Linux environment, but they are requesting it not to have Framework Manager. Is this possible? If so what Cognos BI functions would I use to replace the metadata tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognos Transformer and Cube Designer can publish it's cubes directly to portal.
You can copy metadata as a deployment package from another Cognos BI server.

And you can install Framework Manager on Windows PC and connect it to your Linux Cognos BI Server.

Comment: Thanks, but i will need Framework Manager somewhere in the system(either windows or linux) to be able to create the custom reports?

Comment: You don't need the Framework Manager itself to create reports. However, you will need at least one FWM package to base your reports on. The package is completely architecture indepent, so they can be created on any platform that you choose. On that platform you need to have a single instance of the FWM.

Comment: Ive got looking into Transformer, this needs IBM Cognos Transformer client to be installed on a windows environment to work. Is there any other options? i will not have access to a windows OS to install anything.